# Javascript show next prev content appenchild

Tags: javascript, html

[image]I have multiple divs with same class and I need put only one of class to some id, It show me not right order. And also if I will have some dropdown menu and I will click of some div with class, need to show this class in id. Here is my code, could you please help me. Thanks

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs((slideIndex += n));
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("back").appendChild(x[i]);
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("get").appendChild(x[slideIndex - 1]);
}
```

```css
#get {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

#get .mySlides {
  display: block!important
}
```

```html
<button onclick="plusDivs(-1)"><</button>
<button onclick="plusDivs(1)">></button>
<div id="back">
  <div id="one" class="mySlides">
    <span class="Tx1">111</span>
  </div>
  <div id="two" class="mySlides">
    <span class="Tx1">222</span>
  </div>
  <div id="three" class="mySlides">
    <span class="Tx1">333</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="get"></div>
```

Comment: Can you make it clear what your expected output is?

Comment: I need switcher with buttons and dropdown menu that will show me in some id the content - output of some div.

Comment: still not clear what output you want.  if possible attach some screenshot of output or some image of output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript first's elements index is zero, not 1.

```js
const
  dGet        = document.getElementById('get')
, dBack       = document.getElementById('back')
, slides      = document.querySelectorAll('.mySlides')
, slideSelect = document.querySelector('#slide-Selector')
, current = 
  { slide : null
  , index : 0
  , len   : slides.length
  }; 

  // add slideSelect option elements
for(let indx=0;indx<slides.length;++indx)
  slideSelect.add( new Option( `slide : ${indx+1}`, indx));

slideSelect.onchange =()=>
  {
  current.index = slideSelect.selectedIndex;
  plusDivs(0);
  }

  // init
plusDivs(0);

function plusDivs(n)
  {
    // more easy with a modulo...
  current.index = (current.index +n +current.len) % current.len;
  
  if (current.slide)
    dBack.appendChild( current.slide );
  
  current.slide = dGet.appendChild( slides[current.index] );

  slideSelect.selectedIndex = current.index; // added
  }
```

```css
#get {
  height   : 300px;
  width    : 500px;
  border   : 1px solid red;
  left     : 100px;
  position : absolute;
  }
#back {
  display : none;
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="plusDivs(-1)"><</button>
<button onclick="plusDivs(1)">></button>
<select id="slide-Selector"></select>
<div id="back">
  <div id="one" class="mySlides">
    <span class="Tx1">111</span>
  </div>
  <div id="two" class="mySlides">
    <span class="Tx1">222</span>
  </div>
  <div id="three" class="mySlides">
    <span class="Tx1">333</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="get"></div>
```

Comment: @pt5 added  a HTML select  (== dropdown in your langage)

Comment: And is possible content not append, but copy ?? and switch between with dropdown

Comment: @pt5 The word you ar looking for is **clone** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode.  appendChild make only apear a child to an alement

Comment: Mister Jojo could you please give me a contact I will pay you sometimes a little euro for questions if you would like my email adress is  ocogotv@gmail.com I have now problem with this    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72374105/javascript-clonenode-clone-copy-to-id-with-dropdown-next-prev-buttons   if you would like I will pay you first 4-10 euros please write me email, or you can send me the answer with bank account IBAN dont forget or paypal

Comment: I already done, but if you would help me in future, send me a email, thanks once again for your answers

Comment: @pt5 Sorry, I have enough to do on my side. I just come here as I can.