# Javascript clonenode clone copy to id with dropdown next prev buttons

Tags: javascript, html

please I need solution for my design program, with clonenode/copy

from one big div where user can choose what he would have on concretly id/content, so he could switch it with arrows or choose from dropdown menu,

but I have now solution only with appenchild from div

and, if user add some next content, next id, it will have same big div / it will duplicated so the file will bigger ....

so I need have only one big div from where it will clone or copy to concretly div and this div will not duplicate

many thanks for yours answers

[image]

[image]

```js
const
  dGet        = document.getElementById('get')
, dBack       = document.getElementById('back')
, slides      = document.querySelectorAll('.mySlides')
, slideSelect = document.querySelector('#slide-Selector')
, current = 
  { slide : null
  , index : 0
  , len   : slides.length
  }; 

 
slideSelect.onchange =()=>
  {
  current.index = slideSelect.selectedIndex;
  plusDivs(0);
  }

  // init
plusDivs(0);

function plusDivs(n)
  {
    // more easy with a modulo...
  current.index = (current.index +n +current.len) % current.len;
  
  if (current.slide)
    dBack.appendChild( current.slide );
  
  current.slide = dGet.appendChild( slides[current.index] );

  slideSelect.selectedIndex = current.index; // added
  }
```

```css
#get {
  height   : 300px;
  width    : 500px;
  border   : 1px solid red;
  left     : 100px;
  position : absolute;
  }
#back {
  display : none;
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="plusDivs(-1)"><</button>
<button onclick="plusDivs(1)">></button>
<select id="slide-Selector">
   <option>slideshow1</option>
  <option>slideshow2</option>
  <option>slideshow3</option>
</select>
<div id="back">
  <div id="one" class="mySlides">
    <span class="Tx1">slideshow1</span>
  </div>
  <div id="two" class="mySlides">
    <span class="Tx1">slideshow2</span>
  </div>
  <div id="three" class="mySlides">
    <span class="Tx1">slideshow3</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="get"></div>
```

Comment: You will need to store the data somewhere in your javascript, and then grab that data for each page and replace the innerHTML of the output div with the new content... I highly suggest you to use `<template>` tags for this, so you could pass the data as props using custom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I used `removeChild` and `cloneNode`:

```js
const
  dGet        = document.getElementById('get')
, dBack       = document.getElementById('back')
, slides      = document.querySelectorAll('.mySlides')
, slideSelect = document.querySelector('#slide-Selector')
, current = 
  { slide : null
  , index : 0
  , len   : slides.length
  }
; 

 
slideSelect.onchange =()=>
  {
  current.index = slideSelect.selectedIndex;
  plusDivs(0);
  }

  // init
plusDivs(0);

function plusDivs(n)
  {
    // more easy with a modulo...
  current.index = (current.index +n +current.len) % current.len;
  
  if (current.slide)
    dGet.removeChild( current.slide );
  
  
var clon = slides[current.index].cloneNode(true);
      current.slide = dGet.appendChild(clon);
    

  slideSelect.selectedIndex = current.index; // added
  }
```

```css
#get {
  height   : 300px;
  width    : 500px;
  border   : 1px solid red;
  left     : 100px;
  position : absolute;
  }
#back {
  display : none;
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="plusDivs(-1)"><</button>
<button onclick="plusDivs(1)">></button>
<select id="slide-Selector">
   <option>slideshow1</option>
  <option>slideshow2</option>
  <option>slideshow3</option>
</select>
<div id="back">
  <div id="one" class="mySlides">
    <span class="Tx1">slideshow1</span>
  </div>
  <div id="two" class="mySlides">
    <span class="Tx1">slideshow2</span>
  </div>
  <div id="three" class="mySlides">
    <span class="Tx1">slideshow3</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="get"></div>
```

Comment: now interest me, how can I make variable functions/ id   if user add new content-output